# IOS: How to detect animation is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

This has been asked before but none of the answers are straightforward enough to help little old me.

What exactly does `.isAnimating` in an UIIimage view do? And how to properly use it?

I am emulating the tap to focus animation in the iPhone camera (yellowish square that pops up and then shrinks when  you tap on the preview).  That works fine, but I want it to not happen multiple times if it is already animating.  This code does the animation but multiple taps gives multiple animationed squares.  I suspect it is not just `.isAnimating` but I'm also doing something else wrong because I tried it with my own boolean too and that fails.

```
-(void)focusSquarePopUp:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
{

    UIImage *focusSquareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowFocusSquare"];
    UIImageView *tmpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:focusSquareImage];
    if (!(tmpView.isAnimating))
    {
        tmpView.center = touchPoint;
        tmpView.opaque = YES;
        tmpView.alpha = 1.0f;
        [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
        tmpView.hidden = NO;
        // shrink to half size in .3 second
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        tmpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
        NSLog(@"in animation isAnimating %hhd", tmpView.isAnimating);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Once the animation is completed hide the view for good
            tmpView.hidden = YES;
        }];
    }
    NSLog(@"done animating isAnimating %hhd", tmpView.isAnimating);
    [tmpView release];
}
```

If there is question where this has a solid answer, that would be great.

EDIT - here is the working code.

```
-(void)focusSquarePopUp:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
{

    if (animationInProgress)
        return;
    animationInProgress = true;
    UIImageView *tmpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sp_ui->focus_square];

    tmpView.center = touchPoint;
    tmpView.opaque = YES;
    tmpView.alpha = 1.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
    tmpView.hidden = NO;
    // shrink to half size in .3 second
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        tmpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Once the animation is completed hide the view for good
     tmpView.hidden = YES;
     animationInProgress = false;

    }];

    [tmpView release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isAnimating` is UIImageView property and it has nothing to do with UIView animation methods

`isAnimating` is used when you want a UIImageView to alternate between multiple images. For example in the following code the `UIImageView` display 3 images and alternate between them

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

imageView.animationImages = @[image1, image2, image3];
imageView.animationDuration = 1;

NSLog(@"isAnimating %d",imageView.isAnimating); // isAnimating 0
[imageView startAnimating];
NSLog(@"isAnimating %d",imageView.isAnimating); // isAnimating 1

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Your case is completely different you are using `UIView animation blocks` and to know if the animation in its block is finished or not you will need to add a Boolean flag instance variable `animationFinished` and set it to `YES` in the completion block of the animation

Comment: Thank you, I think Mr. Ibrahim's answer is what I am looking for I will test it ASAP.  Per the earlier answers, I put the declarations in the routine just to have all the code in one place for testing, with the intention of moving them afterwards. It did not occur to me that the location would make a difference.  I'll make both changes and report back over the weekend.  Today, alas, is all meetings.  Thank you both.

Comment: That was the solution indeed, thank you Mr. Ibrahim.  I will clean up the location of the Image and ImageView now, thank you Reformer.

Comment: Stupid Stackoverflow question: How do I post my working code for others who might be interested?  The comments section doesn't allow enough characters.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :) ... However You can edit your original question to add the solution

Answer (score 2):

I suspect on your code. On your tapping on method `focusSquarePopUp:` you create new instances of `tmpView` and `focusSquareImage` and it adding on self view. That why you found number of animated square equal to number of tap. When you create new instance of those variable then sure isAnimating is firstly you got NO value and it enter animation block code.

Why not you create instance of `tmpView` and `focusSquareImage` in .h file of class?? In fact its problem of variable declarations and scope of variables.

Your code should be like this,
Declare instance in animation class (i.e. self.view) .h file

```
 UIImage *focusSquareImage;
 UIImageView *tmpView;
```

Now in .m file viewDidLoad method,

in viewDidLoad

```
focusSquareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowFocusSquare"];
tmpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:focusSquareImage];
```

Your animation method implementation should be,

```
-(void)focusSquarePopUp:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
{
    if (!(tmpView.isAnimating))
    {
        tmpView.center = touchPoint;
        tmpView.opaque = YES;
        tmpView.alpha = 1.0f;
        [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
        tmpView.hidden = NO;
        // shrink to half size in .3 second
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        tmpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
        NSLog(@"in animation isAnimating %hhd", tmpView.isAnimating);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Once the animation is completed hide the view for good
            tmpView.hidden = YES;
            [tmpView release];
        }];
    }
}
```

Another option of method implementation,

```
-(void)focusSquarePopUp:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
{
  if(!tmpView){
    focusSquareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowFocusSquare"];
    tmpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:focusSquareImage];
    if (!(tmpView.isAnimating))
    {
        tmpView.center = touchPoint;
        tmpView.opaque = YES;
        tmpView.alpha = 1.0f;
        [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
        tmpView.hidden = NO;
        // shrink to half size in .3 second
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        tmpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
        NSLog(@"in animation isAnimating %hhd", tmpView.isAnimating);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Once the animation is completed hide the view for good
            tmpView.hidden = YES;
            [tmpView release];
            tmpView = nil;
        }];
    }
 }
}
```